# Image upload doesnt work in IE? But it's fine in other browsers

Tags: php, internet-explorer, image-processing

So I'm facing this issue, one I've never had before in over 4 years of development,

HTML code

```
<fieldset id="step_3" style="display:none;">
  <legend>3. Add Photos</legend>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <label for="main_image">Main Image..</label>
      <input type="file" name="extra_img0" size="35"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="extra_img1">Extra Images</label>
      <input type="file" name="extra_img1" size="35"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="extra_img2"> </label>
      <input type="file" name="extra_img2" size="35" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="extra_img3"> </label>
      <input type="file" name="extra_img3" size="35"/>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Listing"/>
    </li>
  </ol>
</fieldset>
```

And the PHP code...

```
$i = 0;
    while($i < 4) {
        if(!empty($_FILES['extra_img'.$i]['name'])) {
            if($_FILES['extra_img'.$i]['type'] == "image/gif" OR $_FILES['extra_img'.$i]['type'] == "image/png" OR $_FILES['extra_img'.$i]['type'] == "image/jpeg") {
                $img = md5(microtime()).'.jpg';
                $image = New SimpleImage();
                $image->load($_FILES['extra_img'.$i][tmp_name]);
                if($image->getWidth() < $image->getHeight()) {
                    $image->resizeToWidth("300");
                    $image->cutHeight("300");
                } else {
                    $image->resizeToHeight("300");
                    $image->cutWidth("300");
                }
                $image->save('uploads/listings/large/'.$img);
                $db->query("INSERT INTO `images_to_listing` (`listing_id` ,`name`) VALUES ('{$listing_id}', '{$img}');");
            }
        }
    $i++;
    }
```

Code works just fine in all browsers apart from IE? It doesn't even get inserted into MYSQl, any ideas?

Comment: Those `<label>s` are useless in their current form, the `for` attribute maps on to an `id` not a `name`.

Comment: Have you `var_dump()`'d $_FILES to see if it's being sent to the server?

Comment: Add some debug dumps to see *where* it is actually failing. You don't have an `else` on the `if` and you don't check if the database query was successful or print any error messages.

Comment: How is your form defined? I should include the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: You have imgs 1 through 3, but start your loop at 0? You don't have ANY error handling in the code and assume that the upload succeeded, as well as trust the user to actually sent an unhacked `['type']` field. You use unquoted array keys, so most likely you're running with error_reporting and display_errors off, hiding the warnings such thigns cause, etc... In other words, the code's an incipient train wreck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```
// List of allowable file extensions
$allowedExtensions = array (
  'jpg',
  'jpeg',
  'gif',
  'png'
);

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
  // Loop 0-3
  if (!empty($_FILES["extra_img$i"]['name']) && in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["extra_img$i"]['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION),$allowedExtensions))) {
    // If you get here, the image is set and has a file extension specified as allowable above
    $img = md5(microtime()).'.jpg';
    $image = New SimpleImage();
    $image->load($_FILES["extra_img$i"]['tmp_name']);
    if ($image->getWidth() < $image->getHeight()) {
      $image->resizeToWidth("300");
      $image->cutHeight("300");
    } else {
      $image->resizeToHeight("300");
      $image->cutWidth("300");
    }
    $image->save("uploads/listings/large/$img");
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `images_to_listing` (`listing_id` ,`name`) VALUES ('{$listing_id}', '{$img}');");          
  } else {
    // You may want to add error handling here
  }
}
```

The key difference is that is uses the file's extension, rather than it's MIME type (which relies on the browser being sensible).